# transparent background in storyboard viewcontroller

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiviewcontroller, storyboard, uialertview

I am making an login screen. I have the following storyboard.
[image]

What I'm doing in code is. If there is a username and password stored on the device. Than passViewController pops up. Else login viewcontroller pops up. This works fine.

The problem I have is that LoginViewController and PassViewController should have a transparent background. I know how to do this with a single xib file but I want to do this in my storyboard so that I can use my segues from Login and Passviewcontroller to the nextController. At the moment I'm doing this in code.

```
   UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" bundle:nil];
        UIViewController *vc = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"LoginViewController"];
        vc.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        self.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationCurrentContext;
        [self presentModalViewController:vc animated:YES];
```

Can anybody help me how I can achieve this.

Kind regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If my understanding is correct, you just need to click on your view controller's view, for instance, your LoginViewController's view. That's the 1st view in your controller's views hierarchy. Then in the attributes inspector, on your screen's right side, you can set the view's background colour to 'clear colour'. Is that what you're looking for?

Comment: Yes I did that but than I got a black backgound.

Comment: Ok, i can see now what you're trying to do.. You need to set your image as the background image in your viewControllers views. You can do it like this: `self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"image name"]];`

Comment: Yes that can be one solution. But I want it to show up like an alertview that's why i want it to be transparent

Comment: Hmmm.. i'm not sure that this can be achieved without some custom code. This article seems to be addressing the problem you're trying to solve, there might be other ways but it's a start.. http://ramin.firoozye.com/2009/09/29/semi-modal-transparent-dialogs-on-the-iphone/